# design strategy pattern with null checking

Tags: design, design-patterns, null

When the context class can accept a null strategy, is there another way to do it without check if its null?

Is this considered a good strategy design implementation?

```
class MainApp{
    static void Main(){
        Context context = new Context();
        while(true){
            Strategy strategy = createConcreteStrategy(Console.ReadLine());
            context.setStrategy(strategy);
            context.run();
        }
    }
    static void createConcreteStrategy(string input){
        if( input == "strategyA" ){
            return new StrategyA();
        }
        if( input == "strategyB" ){
            return new StrategyB();
        }       
        return null;
    }
}
abstract class Strategy { public abstract void doSomething(); }
class Context{
    Strategy strategy;
    ClassX x;

    public Context(){}
    public void setStrategy(Strategy strategy){
        this.strategy = strategy;
    }
    public void run(){
        if( strategy != null ){
            data = strategy.doSomething();
            x.setData(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is absolutely a way to avoid checking for null here! Use the [null object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern), i.e.

```
class NullStrategy: Strategy {
    public void doSomething() {
    }
}
```

and then the "default" case in `createConcreteStrategy` is `return new NullStrategy()` instead of `return null`, and  then you no longer have to check if `strategy` is null in `run`.

---

If you don't want to call `x.setData` with a null argument, then you could pass `x` to the strategy.  Here's one possible implementation:

```
class NullStrategy: Strategy {
    public void doSomething(ClassX x) {
        // don't do anything with x
    }
}

class RealStrategy: Strategy {
    public void doSomething(ClassX x) {
        var data = someOperation();
        x.setData(data);
    }
}
```

Pushing an if-statement into an instance of `Strategy` makes sense to me in this situation.

Comment: I was thinking about null object pattern as well, but ClassX has to check if data is null. Doesn't that defeat the purpose of null object pattern?

Comment: @user658091 I updated my answer to explain how to avoid that issue.

Comment: +1 I feel the "null object pattern" is a misnomer. It should have been named the NOP Pattern. NOP standing for NO oPeration as in the NOP assembly instruction.